# Using CentOS and get EACCES in home folder

Tags: node.js, centos, ghost

I have a user `www`, and I want it to be the site manager. But get this even in its own home folder:

```
ERROR: EACCES, open '/home/www/ghost_blog/content/images/2015/10/mountain-landscape-wallpaper- 4.jpg'
```

It works when I use `root` account, but not work for `www`. I'm confusing about this authentication.

--- Add ---

I'm using Ghost for my blog application and start with `npm start`, this file is uploaded from client, I'm not sure about the permission about this file.

Comment: What are the permissions on that file and that directory hierarchy?

Comment: @EtanReisner I'm not sure about that file, it is uploaded from client.

Comment: You can't check the permissions on it?